# jBASE 4.1 Database Noobster Questions

Tags: database, installation, multivalue-database

I am a software developer with devlopment experience in C#, C++ .Net alongwith SQL Server 2005/08, Oracle and mysql. But somehow i dont get jBASE to work at Windows XP SP3 machine.

**My goal is setup user accounts, create database on a JBASE ainstallation, authenticate and backup/restore few table via a C++ program. And i dont need to do it with builtin backup/restore tools of jBASE.**

I am able to install jBASe 4.1 aling with all its accessories on my WINXPSP3 machine. I was able to run the jSlimserver and TEMENOUS server along with licnesing server. I was able to add the license key as well. But after that what i was supposed to do? i have no idea about it.

The docs and online help doesnt answer a simple question of how to create a database! The google search results from  the jbase site all go to the 404 Pages!

---

**Can a jBASE expert guide to the following steps:**

1. Create a jBASE database.
2. Create users
3. Authenticate via those users
4. Connect to database
5. Create tables and insert data.
6. Connect via a C++ or C# program to connect to jBASE DB and backup/restore tables.

---

I know that this is too much too ask but i dont get to get the JBASE system. I cant get it to work on my System somehow. *Btw, jdc and jexloree doesnt seem to do anything. I have checked that enironmental variables for jBASE are setup correctly and i have verified them. There are no extra JRE or JDK installations on my system. Besides all that, only licensing client, slim server and temenous server seem to run and listen for connections and no other execuatable ever seems to work.*

**A simple tutorial to achieve the objective will be highly appreciated. Also if anyone can point out the mistake that i have done or anything i might need to check, then please do so. I will be highly encouraged and obliged.**

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Well i need a simple tutorial which may help me achieve

   1. Create a jBASE database.
   2. Create users
   3. Authenticate via those users
   4. Connect to database
   5. Create tables and insert data.
   6. Connect via a C++ or C# program to connect to jBASE DB and backup/restore tables.

So if any body can help me guiding the steps (only) that will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Only question 6 has something to do with SO.

Comment: I think i already know the answer to Q6. After seeing  the docs, i understand that using teh jEDI driver, i can interface with the jBASE database. 

But how i am gonna create a jbase database in the first place.??? Please understand that i have NO experience with jBASE at all. 
Simply stated, i am unable to use jBASE as a database product! I need guidance on how to use it. The documentation isnt enough. I have gone through it and it doesnt seem to be written from a beginner point of view!

Comment: It appears that the docs were written by some jBASE experts for the jBASE Experts. How come a starter supposed to get through jBASE in the first place? I am sorry for the direct talk but i am just trying to be clear enough. I can't get the JbBASE DB System to work. And i dont seem to have any understanding of how to perform the very simple database operations with jBASE in the first place.

I hope i am clear...

Hope to hear a helpful reply from any jBASE expert.

Regards

Comment: Here is my progress..

http://i46.tinypic.com/20sg75e.jpg

Comment: Are you installing T24? Do you have proper jBASE license for your hostname? Anyway I think you better ask Temenos guys for help.

Comment: Three points:

There is a very active jBASE group on Google Groups.  

jBASE does have a habit of redesigning their site to "help better serve their customers."

Setting up jBASE correctly is non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help, if you have not already found a why to do this.

**Setup jBase User and Database**

1. Create a Security Group called
   'Jbase' or what every you want to
   call it
2. Add a User to this group.  I would
   recommend adding your administrator
   user to it as well
3. Create a folder in you file system
   to save the database information
   into
4. Assign the 'Jbase' Security group to
   the folder, and give it "Full"
   read/write/execute access.

**Creating the database:**

5. Make sure the current users you
   are logged on with is the 'Jbase'
   security group.
6. go to the command prompt, and CD
   to the folder you create to store
   the database
7. run the jShell 'jsh' from that
   location
8. use CREATE-FILE to create the
   files/tables you want to store your
   information in.

**Inserting data:**
There are several ways to enter data.  You can use ED, your can your programming environment, or you can create a quick MultiValue/jBase compiled server script to ask for the data and write them to a file/table.